# IntelliJ 2022.2.2 JDBC PostgreSQL driver error

Tags: java, postgresql, intellij-idea, jdbc

I've been looking for ages now, trying to get my JDBC driver to work.

This is, what I've tried so far:

This is my init function, where I call Class.forName( .. ); to load the class.

```
public void init() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(this.dbUrl, this.user,
            this.password);
}
```

This is also represented in my run configuration, which looks like this:
[image: Run/Debug Configuration]

org.postgresql.driver is located inside the postgresql-42.5.0.jar

I also added the jar to the dependencies of my project. It looks likes this:

[image: Project Dependencies]

It's added to the Project Libraries as well:

[image: Project Libraries]

But still, when I try to run my program, it throws an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test"
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at webservice.util.sql.libs.SQLConnector.init(SQLConnector.java:26)
at webservice.util.sql.libs.SQLConnectorImpl.main(SQLConnectorImpl.java:17)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

I could really need some help, getting my program to run.

Comment: That's weird. I just tested this locally and it works fine. It even works when I remove the `Class.forName(...)` statement. The PostgreSQL should load automatically when the jar file is on the classpath. And it seems to be on your classpath as you seem to be able to load the class. Also, it is sufficient to only add the driver jar to the dependencies. You don't have to define a library for this. Last but not least, you should separate your src from your library. You should place the driver jar in a separate folder, e.g. lib. Please also check your run config. You might have messed up things...

Comment: In my running configuration, I added the Class "org.postgresql.Driver", which is located inside the postgresql-42.5.0.jar/org.postgresql/Driver.class. I also changed the driver location to ./lib/postgresql-42.5.0.jar. I still get the same error..

Edit: The driver did work when running in eclipse, but now I can finally get IntelliJ again so I switched ^^

Comment: Also, when inside the Database tab of IntelliJ, I can connect to the database with no problem at all.. but it uses a driver somewhere else. I was not able to locate it really tho..

Comment: You added the class to code coverage. That's used when testing your code. But you dont want to test the postgre SQL driver, do you? So you better remove that, remove the library and just add the jar to dependencies in your module settings. Maybe remove the run-configuration and create a new one.

Comment: Still the same error message..

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.. the error message was a little confusing..

I load my userdata from a properties file and had the data in quotes ("").

The error message looked okay, but it was actually looking for a connection with "" ..